# Cosa è un "uomo in ammollo"?

Tags: sentences

So cosa significa ammollare o "in ammollo". Per esempio, metter i panni in ammollo, cioè immergerli in liquido (acqua di solito) per renderli molli.

Ma cosa è esattamente un "uomo in ammollo"? Per esempio, nella canzone "Dimmi Dimmi Tu" di Frankie HI-NRG MC, quest'ultimo dice durante la prima strofa: "...giù fino al midollo tu ci sei immerso quasi come l'uomo in ammollo."

Non ci ho mai fatto veramente caso a quest'espressione, quindi sarebbe interessante capire quando è più indicato usarla e quali sono veramente i possibili significati di un "uomo in ammollo". La mia idea è che un uomo in ammollo è tipo un uomo che galleggia, cioè quindi che non ha veramente il controllo (di qualcosa), e quindi si fa trasportare (per esempio dalla società?).

Answer (score 6):

L'espressione fa riferimento ad un [famoso spot di un detersivo](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjptIqUiIbUAhWL6xQKHdz2A9EQtwIIPjAH&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D0gfXdK9rXp0&usg=AFQjCNEhFnO4KRqQI42vk2RRER2bFxUNHg), andato in onda sulla televisione italiana tra gli anni '70 e '80.

Negli anni ’70 l’uomo in ammollo era il chitarrista jazz [Franco Cerri](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franco_Cerri).

> Autoironico, casalingo e rassicurante, Cerri se ne stava beatamente
>   immerso in acqua, tutto vestito in camicia e cravatta, spiegando come
>   la potenza di Bio Presto avrebbe cancellato le terribili macchie di
>   cui era cosparsa la sua camicia.
>
> «Sporco impossibile? Nooo, non esiste sporco impossibile per Bio
>   Presto» era il tormentone della campagna, che durò 15 anni e negli
>   anni ’80 continuò a mostrarci Cerri che, oltre a stare in acqua,
>   girava per case e supermercati, sempre occupandosi (come una donna!)
>   di lavatrici, detersivi e panni sporchi.
>
> Oggi il testimonial è Umberto Pelizzari, campione mondiale di apnea
>   profonda, e la headline delle affissioni è «Un pulito da record».
>
> La differenza è lampante: **negli anni ’70-’80 Bio Presto rappresentava
>   un uomo piacente ma normale, pronto a mettere da parte le sue abilità
>   di chitarrista per pensare al bucato**; oggi ci mostra un recordman dal
>   fisico eccezionale, al cui volto, in realtà segnato da sole e mare, il
>   fotoritocco ha cancellato rughe e imperfezioni, per omologarlo a mille
>   altri belloni da passerella.

Direi che il significato non è quello che indichi tu (uomo che galleggia e che non ha il controllo della situazione) ma è specificatamente riferito allo spot di Cerri, divenuto più famoso per quello che per la sua grande carriera come musicista (è uno dei tre chitarristi italiani con [una voce inserita nell'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/franco-cerri/)).

Come ho sottolineato dal [blog di Giovanna Cosenza](https://giovannacosenza.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/luomo-in-ammollo/):

> negli anni ’70-’80 Bio Presto rappresentava
>   un uomo piacente ma normale, pronto a mettere da parte le sue abilità
>   di chitarrista per pensare al bucato

ed inoltre:

> negli anni ’80 continuò a mostrarci Cerri che, oltre a stare in acqua,
>   girava per case e supermercati, sempre occupandosi (come una donna!)
>   di lavatrici, detersivi e panni sporchi.